# How to prepare node.js modules on 64bit for 32bit system?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, raspbian

I'm developing a node.js application on a 64bit Ubuntu machine that I intend to run on a Raspberry Pi running Rasbpian. The Pi is not usually connected to the internet, so I manually copy the project folder to its SD card. I can't run the application there since one of the required modules, `epoll`, apparently only works with 64 bit:

> Error: /home/pi/bla/node_modules/epoll/build/Release/epoll.node: wrong
>   ELF class: ELFCLASS64
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:602:18)
>
> at Module.load (module.js:507:32) at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
>
> at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
>
> at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>
> at bindings (/home/pi/bla/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
>
> at Object. (/home/pi/bla/node_modules/epoll/epoll.js:1:99)
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)

This can be fixed by running `npm uninstall epoll` and then `npm install epoll`, but only when the Pi is connected to the internet. Of course I could just not copy this specific module, but is there a way to avoid this error otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't anything to do with copying, it's because your trying to run packages that have been compiled using a 64-bit Node version under a 32-bit version.

Compile your packages using the same bitness of Node on your Ubuntu system (you can install 32-bit Node on a 64-bit OS) and *then* copy them over.

Comment: Yes I didn't think that the process of copying causes problems; I wasn't sure how to install 32bit node modules on a 64bit system though. I adapted the question title. Thanks!

Comment: @speedymcs you should install [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), it's as simple as `nvm use <version> 32`

Answer (score 1):

If you have no internet connection on install, then the only way is to prepare both 32bit and 64bit node_modules beforehand. On first launch, just check your CPU and make `node_modules` symlink to `node_modules_64` or `node_modules_32`.